# Contenteditable: How to completely remove span when pressing del or backspace

Tags: javascript, html, range, selection

I have a [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) div, as shown in HTML below (caret marked by `|`).

I would like to remove `span.label` when pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> (i.e. the span acts as a single letter, thus to the user it looks as if `Name` was deleted in one single keypress)

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   Hallo, <span class="label">Name</span>|,
   this is a demonstration of placeholders!
   Sincerly, your
   <span class="label">Author</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to check if the cursor is at the exact position of the end of the span, and if so - remove it:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // Check for a backspace
    if (event.which == 8) {
        s = window.getSelection();
        r = s.getRangeAt(0)
        el = r.startContainer.parentElement
        // Check if the current element is the .label
        if (el.classList.contains('label')) {
            // Check if we are exactly at the end of the .label element
            if (r.startOffset == r.endOffset && r.endOffset == el.textContent.length) {
                // prevent the default delete behavior
                event.preventDefault();
                if (el.classList.contains('highlight')) {
                    // remove the element
                    el.remove();
                } else {
                    el.classList.add('highlight');
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    event.target.querySelectorAll('span.label.highlight').forEach(function(el) { el.classList.remove('highlight');})
});
```

```css
span.label.highlight {
    background: #E1ECF4;
    border: 1px dotted #39739d;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
 Hallo, <span class="label">Name</span>|,
 this is a demonstration of placeholders!
</div>
```

> I didn't implement the `del` key functionality, but the general idea is there and I think you can complete it based on the above example

Comment: Wow, this is the first time, I get a helpful answer to a javascript range/selection question that acually works. Great job!

Comment: I actually answered several questions regarding range/selection in the past :) glad I could help.

Comment: @Delel, could you suggest a good reading about the range and selection stuff? I have several other gotchas to tackle as we are implementing a Label and `@mention` system in our app right now.

Comment: mdn is a really good place to start, and you are welcome to ask more questions here (you can ping me in a comment here)

Comment: btw - if it was me I wouldn't delete it immediately - i would probably add another class to that span to mark/highlight it, and only on the second backspace delete it... better UX

Comment: I think I will do it that way, but at the moment we are in a proof-of-concept phase to see if we can implement it and then the UX and UI guys make a design for how it should look and behave exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151661/discussion-between-tobi-and-dekel).

Answer (score 0):

You can listened to onKeyDown event on the div:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable">
 Hallo, <span class="label">Name</span>|,
 this is a demonstration of placeholders!
</div>
```

Here is the event listening handler:

```
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            var keycode = event.keyCode;
            console.log(keycode);
            if (keycode === 8 || keycode === 46) {
                var spnLables = document.querySelectorAll('#editable span.label');
                if (spnLables.length) {
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(spnLables, function (thisnode) {
                        document.getElementById('editable').removeChild(thisnode);
                    });

                }

            }
        });
```